# change the year of a date in R

Tags: r, date, data.table

I want to rewrite the year in my data, such that `from` consist of a combination of the year in `year` column and month and day from the `from` column

```
example <- structure(list(year = 2016:2017, 
                          from = structure(c(16828L,16828L), 
                                               class = c("IDate", "Date"))), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table","data.frame"))
```

My data set is very large, so I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

Comment: `example %>% 
  separate(from,into= c("year1","month","day"),sep="-") %>% 
  mutate(year = paste(year,month,day,sep="-")) %>% 
  select(year)`  is this your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `lubridate` `year` for assignment

```
library(lubridate)
example$from <- as.Date(example$from)
year(example$from) <- example$year
```

-output

```
> example
    year       from
   <int>     <Date>
1:  2016 2016-01-28
2:  2017 2017-01-28
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `format()`, combine the year from `year` with the month and day of `from` in `data.table` (which you seem to already be using).
 The symbol `%m` stands for two-digit month, and the symbol `%d` stands for two-digit day.

```
example[, from := format(from, paste0(year,"-%m-%d"))]
example
   year       from
1: 2016 2016-01-28
2: 2017 2017-01-28
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.

Comment: @Jbadminton added some explaner, but I thought because this question was pretty clear the output didn't really require any.